# In if statement one line works others don't

Tags: python, if-statement

```
a = 0
b = 0

def check():
    if (pya.locateOnScreen("image.PNG") != None):
        print("Found")
        a = 1
    else:
        print("Not found")
        b = 1

check()
print(a,b)
```

Output is:

```
Found
0 0
```

Even though it finds the image, it doesn't change the value of a.

I think the output should be:

```
Found
1 0
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: a is creating a local variable in the function, and not referring to the global variable a.

Comment: `a` and `b` are local to the scope of `check()`. If you want to use them outside that scope, you can return them or (less preferred) set them as global variables.